# How to use es6 to let or const within if statement

Tags: ecmascript-6

If I use `let` or `const` within a container controlling a page within a reactjs page it causes errors. If I use `var` it works fine. What am I missing understanding?

```
export default CareerHistoryContainer = createContainer(({match, isCandidate, isAdmin}) => {
  if (isCandidate) {
    var profileCandidateCollectionHandle = Meteor.subscribe('profileCandidate.private');
    var loading = !profileCandidateCollectionHandle.ready();
    var profileCandidateCollection = ProfileCandidate.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()});
    var profileCandidateCollectionExist = !loading && !!profileCandidateCollection;
  }

  if (isAdmin) {
    var adminProfileCandidatesubscribeSubscribe = Meteor.subscribe('admin.candidateProfile', (match.params.userId));
    var loading = !adminProfileCandidatesubscribeSubscribe.ready();
    var profileCandidateCollection = ProfileCandidate.findOne({userId: match.params.userId});
    var profileCandidateCollectionExist = !loading && !!profileCandidateCollection;
  }

  return {
    loading,
    profileCandidateCollection,
    profileCandidateCollectionExist,
    profileCandidate: profileCandidateCollectionExist
      ? profileCandidateCollection
      : {}
  };
}, CareerHistoryFormPage);
```

Comment: *What* errors? And why are you declaring variables in this code at all when they're used nowhere?

Comment: I've updated with more info. The page can be accessed by Admin or Candidate. If I use `const` or `let` it says `loading is not defined`.

Comment: `let` and `const` are block scoped. `{const a = 1} console.log(a) // cause ReferenceError`

Comment: Does that mean `var` is right in this situation?

Comment: @bp123 Yes of course, if you use `let` or `const` then you haven't declared the variable in the function scope where the `return` is. Even with `var` it's weird - `loading` has the value `undefined` when neither condition is met.

Comment: What would be the correct way to write this then? Still a noob.

Comment: BTW what would expect your code to do if both `isAdmin` and `isCandidate` were false?

Comment: If they were both false then the page won't load and the server won't push down any data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ES6, `let` and `const` variables definitions are block scoped, while `var` isn't.

```
if (isCandidate) {
    let profileCandidateCollectionHandle = Meteor.subscribe('profileCandidate.private');
    let loading = !profileCandidateCollectionHandle.ready();
    let profileCandidateCollection = ProfileCandidate.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()});
    let profileCandidateCollectionExist = !loading && !!profileCandidateCollection;
    // Here, the 4 variables are only visible inside the block
}

// Here, you can't see, use or modify them
// so if you do like
return loading;

// will return exception: `loading` not defined
```

```
if (isCandidate) {
    var profileCandidateCollectionHandle = Meteor.subscribe('profileCandidate.private');
    var loading = !profileCandidateCollectionHandle.ready();
    var profileCandidateCollection = ProfileCandidate.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()});
    var profileCandidateCollectionExist = !loading && !!profileCandidateCollection;

}
// Here, the 4 variables are kept, you can do everything you want on them
// so if you do like
return loading;

// will return the right value
```

See more at: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html

For your example, you can do something like this to fix the problem:

```
export default CareerHistoryContainer = createContainer(({match, isCandidate, isAdmin}) => {
    // declaring here, variables will only be seen 
    // inside this block and sub blocks
    let profileCandidateCollectionHandle;
    let loading;
    let profileCandidateCollection;

    if (isCandidate) {
        profileCandidateCollectionHandle = Meteor.subscribe('profileCandidate.private');
        loading = !profileCandidateCollectionHandle.ready();
        profileCandidateCollection = ProfileCandidate.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()});
    }

    if (isAdmin) {
        profileCandidateCollectionHandle = Meteor.subscribe('admin.candidateProfile', (match.params.userId));
        loading = !profileCandidateCollectionHandle.ready();
        profileCandidateCollection = ProfileCandidate.findOne({userId: match.params.userId});

    }

    let profileCandidateCollectionExist = !loading && !!profileCandidateCollection;

    return {
        loading,
        profileCandidateCollection,
        profileCandidateCollectionExist,
        profileCandidate: profileCandidateCollectionExist
             ? profileCandidateCollection
             : {}
    };
}, CareerHistoryFormPage);
```

Comment: Thanks @nathael. Sorry about the time delay. Really good explanation, that makes a lot more sense. Why is it `better` to use this code than just using `var`? I'm just curious.

Comment: Just because of security reasons (I don't know if there is other differences like performance or other); using `var` also allows to fail writing line at wrong place and program will work without saying there is an error (ans so you will spend much more time debugging); Always better to use maximise constraints to avoid errors and "hack"/wrong use of your work :P

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the insight.